# scanf() and for loop not cooperating

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf

I'm writing a function called `GetPattern()` that will be used in my `main()` function.

Here's the context of how my `main()` uses the `GetPattern()` function.

```
int main(void)
{
  int attempt=0, option=-1;
  char pattern[SIZE+1], replacement[SIZE+1];
  char name[20];    
  FILE *in, *out;

  printf("Enter the pattern to find:");
  GetPattern(pattern);
  out = CreateFile();
  Find(in, pattern, out);
  fclose(in);
  fclose(out);

  return 0;
}
```

And here's my `GetPattern()` function:

```
void GetPattern(char *tmp)
{
// prompt the user for the pattern to be found/replaced
// note: any character, including ' ', maybe be part of the pattern
// we assume that the pattern has no more than 20 characters. If the user
// enters more than 20 characters, only the first 20 will be used.

  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) // iterate 20 times
    {
      scanf(" %c", &tmp[i]);
      if (tmp[i] == '\n') // if user hits enter, break the loop
        {
          tmp[i] = '\0'; // insert '\0' at the end of the array
          break;
        }
      else
        tmp[i+1] = '\0'; // insert '\0' at the end of the array
    }

  printf("%s\n", tmp); // see what's in tmp[]

  return;
}
```

The `GetPattern()` function works by itself; separate from the `main()` function, but when I put it into `main`, it exclusively accepts 20 characters and no less. Even when I hit ENTER (i.e., '\n'), the loop doesn't break--it keeps going.

Do you see anything obviously wrong with this code?

Comment: The space in `" %c"` means "skip whitespace". That includes newlines. So `tmp[i]` will never be `'\n'`.

Comment: Ugh. You've got to be kidding me. There's no winning with this language. Thank you @user3386109.

Comment: When the user hits `[Enter]` alone there is no character for scanf to read and thus no conversion takes place. `scanf` sits there happily waiting for a character no matter how many times `[Enter]` is pressed. End of input is marked with `[ctrl+d]` (`[ctrl+z]` on windows).

Comment: Well, don't judge C, the _language_, by the actions of a single semi-standard function.  I've been programming in C for 30+ years, and I have _never_ [not _once_] ever used scanf et. al.  I've always used fgets, fgetc, strtok, strtol, atoi, etc. instead.  Why?  Well, just my opinion, but when I first looked at scanf, my take on it was that it was _malignant_ :-).  And, I felt that I could handle more general cases better by _not_ using scanf.  But, others use it with success--YMMV

Comment: the `scanf()` family of functions has many capabilities that must all be accounted for.   Suggest using: `fgets( tmp, 20, stdin ); as that single command will handle everything you want to do.    However, strongly suggest NOT using 'magic' numbers (like the 20) but rather use a #define to give that number a meaningful name then using that meaningful name throughout the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think using `getc()` will help you.

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) // iterate 20 times
{
    //scanf(" %c", &tmp[i]);
    tmp[i]=getc(stdin);/////

    if (tmp[i] == '\n') // if user hits enter, break the loop
    {
        tmp[i] = '\0'; // insert '\0' at the end of the array
        break;
    }
    else
        tmp[i+1] = '\0'; // insert '\0' at the end of the array
}
```